# android - How to scan barcode and QR Code using one Scanner

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I need the scanner that scans the bar code as well as QR code.For this i saw one App in the Play Store is [QR Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_progetto2003.SCAN&hl=en).But i don't how to integrate this to android application.
I want the best scanner either it is free or paid and that is easily integrate to android application.Please give me your valuable suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use zxing (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). It provides a number of way to integrate bar code/QR code scanning.

Personally I like the method using intent. It is very easy and robust soultion. You can read more from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).

Comment: is it scans the QR-Code as well or it scans the only bar code?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/#integration%2Fandroid
You will find a few java files. IntentResult is there too.

Comment: Actually i Used it in the tab bar but i don't know how to use the onActivityResult().plz can u tell me how to use it?